Unable to restrict the input range of a EditText
I am trying to restrict the input of an EditText that's inputType is "Number" however it refuses to limit itself from going past 100, I am unsure of why it's doing that despite my best efforts
This is what the specific XML that i'm trying to target looks like, it is in a relative layout and is part of a fragment
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tfInterest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvInterest"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="start|top"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="3"
        />

This is the activity where the code I'm attempting to write is in
class RegisterFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentRegisterBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
         binding = FragmentRegisterBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        val tfInterest = binding.tfInterest
        tfInterest.filters = arrayOf(NumberRangeFilter())
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register, container, false)
    }

  class NumberRangeFilter : InputFilter {

        override fun filter(
            source: CharSequence?,
            start: Int,
            end: Int,
            dest: Spanned?,
            dstart: Int,
            dend: Int
        ): CharSequence? {
            val input = source.toString()
            val value = try {
                Integer.parseInt(input)
            } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
                return ""
            }

            // Check if the input is within the range of 1 to 100
            return if (value in 1..100) {
                // Check if the resulting text will be within the range of 1 to 100 after replacement
                val newValue = dest.toString().substring(0, dstart) + input + dest.toString().substring(dend)
                val newValueInt = try {
                    Integer.parseInt(newValue)
                } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
                    return ""
                }
                if (newValueInt in 1..100) {
                    null // Accept input
                } else {
                    "" // Reject input
                }
            } else {
                "" // Reject input if it's outside the range
            }
        }
    }
}

I am unsure on how to proceed, I am welcome to alternative methods than the one I am attempting, I just need to make sure any inputs are within 1 to 100

Two layered issue:
First you inflate binding, attach a filter to the binding view, but later you inflate a view layout once more and use it. Hence, you render an another view without the filter set.
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
         binding = FragmentRegisterBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        val tfInterest = binding.tfInterest
        tfInterest.filters = arrayOf(NumberRangeFilter())
        return binding.getRoot() // instead of another inflate return the binding view
    }

You can easily detect such issues by attaching the debugger or adding log call to find if your code is reachable.
Also a simple InputFilter implementation:
    class NumberRangeFilter: InputFilter {
        override fun filter(
            source: CharSequence?,
            start: Int,
            end: Int,
            dest: Spanned?,
            dstart: Int,
            dend: Int
        ): CharSequence {
            val builder = SpannableStringBuilder()
                .append(dest)
                .replace(dstart, dend, source)

            val numberText = builder.toString()
            val number = numberText.toIntOrNull()
            if (number.toString() == numberText && number in 0..100)
                return source ?: ""
            else
                return ""
        }
    }


I see, I apologize for something so simple than
I'm not quite familiar with android studio nor its debugging tools, thanks for the answer
